# How to add column with range values to DataFrame

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have dataframe with the current structure

```
user_id | country | event |
1       | CA      | 1     |
2       | USA     | 1     |
```

and I want to add the new column with period range (0-n) and get something like this

```
user_id | country | event |period|
1       | CA      | 1     |1
1       | CA      | 1     |2
1       | CA      | 1     |...
1       | CA      | 1     |n

2       | USA     | 1     |1
2       | USA     | 1     |2
2       | USA     | 1     |...
2       | USA     | 1     |n
```

As I understand it should be some window function and `withColumn` function

```py
w = (Window.partitionBy(['user_id', 'country', 'event'])
df = df.withColumn('period', (???).over(w))
```

How I can add the new column and at the same time new rows by some range?

Answer (score 2):

First use [`spark.range()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.SparkSession.range) to create a second DataFrame containing the periods. For example, with `n=3`:

```
n = 3
periods = spark.range(1, n+1).withColumnRenamed("id", "period")
periods.show()
#+------+
#|period|
#+------+
#|     1|
#|     2|
#|     3|
#+------+
```

Now [`crossJoin`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.crossJoin) this with `df` to get the desired output:

```
df = df.crossJoin(periods)
df.show()
#+-------+-------+-----+------+
#|user_id|country|event|period|
#+-------+-------+-----+------+
#|      1|     CA|    1|     1|
#|      1|     CA|    1|     2|
#|      1|     CA|    1|     3|
#|      2|    USA|    1|     1|
#|      2|    USA|    1|     2|
#|      2|    USA|    1|     3|
#+-------+-------+-----+------+
```

Note that `range` doesn't actually materialize the DataFrame, so the Cartesian product will not be expensive.

```
df.explain()
#== Physical Plan ==
#BroadcastNestedLoopJoin BuildRight, Cross
#:- Scan ExistingRDD[user_id#0,country#1,event#2]
#+- BroadcastExchange IdentityBroadcastMode
#   +- *(1) Project [id#31L AS period#33L]
#      +- *(1) Range (1, 4, step=1, splits=2)
```

Comment: What if the groups are of different lengths?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Can you give an example?